# Need ScriptReferenceProfiler.dll or alternate

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I improving site performance and for that, I try to Bundle or combine ScriptResource.axd and Webresource.axd but before combine to I need to know javascript file reference name which is used by ajax control toolkit in asp.net web form
like this https://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/

I need ScriptReferenceProfiler.DLL to get a reference of the javascript file which is used in ajax toolkit on the web page. 
do you have any idea to get this dll file

I go through this tutorial 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/using-script-combining-to-improve-ajax-performance

Or if you have any alternate solution please let me know

Comment: what you want exactly to do? make it more clear what are you doing

Comment: I improving site performance and for that, I try to Bundle or combine ScriptResource.axd and Webresource.axd but before combine to I need to know javascript file reference name which is used by ajax control toolkit in asp.net web form
like this [https://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you looking and reference from the link you add was here : http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/13356

I can not find it now so I uploaded for you here, both source code and binaries.

http://planethost.gr/so/ScriptReferenceProfiler.zip

http://planethost.gr/so/ScriptReferenceProfilerBinaries.zip